# how to get php echo statements into predefind list?

Tags: jquery

how to get php echo statements into predefind list?

I have this test.php file on the server that echo back four statements....like this:

```
                         echo "<p> Test Results 1</p>";
                         echo "<p> Test Results 2</p>";
                         echo "<p> Test Results 3</p>";
                         echo "<p> Test Results 4</p>";
```

I request this information using an ajax $.post request like this:

```
            $.post("test.php", function(data)
            {
                $.each(data, function(key, value) 
                {
                  $("#testResults li:eq(key)").append(value); 
                });
            });                
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

I need to put them into predefind list like this:

```
           <ul id="testResults">    
                     <li></li>
                     <li></li>
                     <li></li>
                     <li></li>
           </ul>
```

Comment: can the server return more or less than 4 paragraphs? Or are they always 4?

Comment: It seems that `data` in the callback will be just string, so `$.each(data...` will be incorrect. I'd recommend use JSON instead, but if the format of input is fixed try to make this: `$.each($(data), ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.post("test.php", function(data)
        {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) 
            {
              $("#testResults)").append('<li id="'+key+'">'+value+'</li>'); 
            });
        });                
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

This code will add  li tags to the ul id="testResults"
The key of the requests will be the id of the appended li tags.

Hope this is what you need.

Comment: thanks dlmitril but I need to add echo statements to predefind list not add new list

Comment: also, using your solution, the output comes out vertically with only one character per list, long list..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure on the Javascript for this one. But you should try returning an array in php that holds those four values. This way you can access each element of the array and send back as much data as you like.